# How do I install lxml in linux without using aptitude or apt-get

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, lxml

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and usually use python 2.7, but I need a python package that was built with python 3.4 and that uses lxml. After updating aptitude, I can install python 3.2 and lxml, but the package I want only works with 3.4.  After installing python 3.4, I try to install lxml dependencies using

```
pip3 install libxml2-dev
```

I get the error:

```
No matching distribution found for libxml2-dev

pip3 install lxml
```

doesn't work and asks for libxml2:

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
```

Any ideas on how to install lxml?  Thanks.

Comment: You should build and install from source. https://github.com/lxml/lxml.git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running

```
pip3 install libxml2-dev
```

when you should be running

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev
```

(you may also need `libxslt` and its dev version as well)

`pip` doesn't install system libraries, `apt` and friends do that.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libxml2... installs libxml2 for either python 2.7 or 3.2 which are supported by apt-get.  I need libxml2 for python 3.4.

Comment: @user1106278 I think you misread the answer. You need to have libxml2-dev installed (`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`) before you can install lxml with `pip3 install lxml`.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libxml-python

Download the package and then do a `pip install <package.whl>`.

Comment: I'm running linux, but the webpage title says "windows binaries."  Would it still work?